# What is a router plane fence designed for?

Tags: hand-tools, plane

Recently I bought a veritas router plane and I noticed that they provide an optional fence.
（and with smaller blades）

[image: Router Plane]
As I'm new to woodworking, I wonder what the fence is designed for?
It seems one can make grooves using a router plane with a fence？Then how about a plow/plough plane？

Whats the difference between a router plane with fence
and a plow plane in making grooves？dados or rabbets？

Thanks

Comment: The router plane will not do a good job with dados (i.e. cross-grain grooves) as it has no way to sever the fibers as it goes deeper.  Typically planes designed to cut dados or cross-grain rabbets have small vertical "nicker" knives in front of the iron to sever the fibers before the main waste is removed.  If you want to use a router plane to cut a dado you'll have to either cut the side walls with a saw beforehand or score them with a single-bevel knife every few passes.

Comment: The basic answer here is that the fence, *like all such similar fences* is to ensure the plane works at a fixed distance in from an edge. Planes, routers (both powered and manual), scratch stocks, certain saws and even some models of spokeshave, all use their fences for this purpose.

Comment: The fence is designed to pull more money from your pocket. I know because I purchased the fence and have never found a reason to use it. And I use my router plane all of the time.

Answer (score 1):

I recently purchased the same router plane as well along with the fence which I haven't used yet, but after cutting my first few dados, I can see why it would be helpful. I'm new as well so I imagine that with experience, you may not need the fence. The fence is to keep the blade parallel to an edge, which is the same purpose as on the plow plane. For the router plane, the fence mitigates small changes in the angle of the blade which slowly makes the cut wider.  The main differences between the two is the router is referenced from the face of the board, so it's good for keeping the depth of the cut level, but the blade is short, so it's easier to get off line if you rotate the plane while cutting.  The plow plane is longer and references against the edge so it's better for cutting with the grain and staying straight.  I'm sure you found the same sites as well, but this blog was helpful to me - [Veritas Router plane as a plow plane](https://sawmillcreek.org/showthread.php?192582-Veritas-Router-Plane-as-a-plough-plane)

For dados, there are dado planes (of course) as well. I don't own this one, but it gets good reviews.  [dado plane](https://www.heartwoodtools.com/hntgordon/dado-plane-quarter-inch#:%7E:text=1%2F4%20inch-,Dado%20Plane%20%2D%201%2F4%20inch,when%20planing%20across%20the%20grain.)